# How to iterate over all columns of dataset in spark (java)

Tags: java, apache-spark, foreach, iteration

I have a dataset with many columns (actuall 11000 but it could be more) and around 40000 rows. What I am trying to do is to apply a UDF to all these columns (this UDF simply shortens the strings of the columns by replacing them with a character). My approach works fine but it is really inefficient, since I use a for-loop to iterate all columns. Is there any opportunity to use the foreach() function or something like that in order to parallelize the execution on all 11000 columns?

```java
        sqlContext.udf().register("replaceStringByChar", replaceStringByChar, DataTypes.StringType);


        for (String c : ds.columns()) {
            ds = ds.withColumn(c, functions.callUDF("replaceStringByChar", ds.col(c)));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should works

```java
ds.columns().foreach(column -> {
  System.out.println("Column" + column);
});
```

Comment: I think I cannot apply foreach() on columns(),

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution using `withColumns` method of the `Dataset<Row>` object. check this post:
[Iterate over different columns using withcolumn in Java Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59953752/iterate-over-different-columns-using-withcolumn-in-java-spark/60037090#60037090)
For your case woul be something like this:

```
List<String> fieldsNameList = ds.columns();
Seq<String> fieldsNameSeq = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(fieldsNameList).seq();

List<Column> whenColumnList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList());

for (String c : ds.columns()) {
        Column whenColumn = functions.callUDF("replaceStringByChar", ds.col(c))
        whenColumnList.add(whenColumn)
}

Seq<Column> whenColumnSeq = JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(whenColumnList).seq();

Dataset<Row>  ds_new = ds.withColumns(fieldsNameSeq, whenColumnSeq);
```